# Creating a 404 page with HashRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, custom-error-pages

I have created a NotFound page that should be displayed when I type a non-available URL. I must use HashRouter in my app. The code below works whey I type example.com/#/somethingwrong but not for example.com/somethingwrong.

**index.js**

```
const app = (
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <HashRouter>
        <App />
      </HashRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

**app.js**

```
return (
    <ScrollToTop>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={MainScreen} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </ScrollToTop>
  );
```

Comment: `HashRouter` only handles everything after the hash and your app is rendered on `"/#/"`, not `"/"`.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is **HashRouter** you have to put path="/(asterik symbol)" instead of path="(astertik symbol)". It works for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me unfortunately. I don't think it is even possible based on Drew's comment above.